# how to get the account information in microsoft one drive/sky drive php sdk

Tags: php, onedrive

I am generating an application for the cloud search with integration of some cloud plateform . I am working on the microsoft sky drive . everything is fine but i need the account information means the user id and username. please help me . i am using this php sdk

```
function get_user() {
        $response = curl_get(skydrive_base_url."/users?access_token=".$this->access_token);
        if (@array_key_exists('error', $response)) {
            throw new Exception($response['error']." - ".$response['description']);
            exit;
        } else {    
            return $response['link'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to do a `GET` using a `USER_ID` for a particular user or `me` to get information about the currently signed in user

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/USER_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Or for information about the signed-in user

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It returns user id, but not username. You also receive user name, first name, last name, gender, and locale.

Further information available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659736.aspx

Comment: thanx Jeanine M S  .. .